# Report with Chapters Starting on Odd Pages with Equal Margins in all Pages and NO GEOMETRY

Tags: geometry, mdframed, report

I am trying to get the chapters of my document to start only on odd pages (that is, on the right; as good typsetting practices recommend). I have tried to use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}
```

Of course, this achieves what I want, but it also changes the margins of even and odd pages. **This is a behaviour I want to avoid**. Therefore, I have tied to use the powerful geometry package to get margins as close as possible to normal (original) report margins. I do so by specifying the following line in the preamble (I know these are not exactly the report margins; but it's the closest I can get given I do not know how to specify exactly the original report margins with `geometry`):

```
\usepackage[top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=4.5cm,right=4.5cm]{geometry}
```

However, this generates a **strange behaviour**. In short, when using the `geometry` package and specifying the margins I want, some pages change completely their layout. The document I am typesetting is full of theorems, definitions, examples and proofs; that I specify using `mdframed`. However, when loading `geometry` in the way I do it, some of the pages completely change their layout. That is, the spacing between mdframed environments becomes arbitrary too large in some pages. As you can guess, **the issue is quite hard to reproduce with a MWE**. Hence, I can provide no MWE this time (I am really sorry). What I can easily provide are two screenshots that show what I mean:

[image]

[image]

The first picture is what I get with `\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}` and `\usepackage[top=4cm,bottom=4cm,left=4.5cm,right=4.5cm]{geometry}`; the second picture is the original one with `\documentclass[a4paper]{report}` and no `geometry`. I guess that is easy to see that what I want is to **avoid this rather strange vertical spacing behaviour** of the first screenshot when loading `geometry`. Therefore, my questions boil down to:

*Is there anyway of getting chapters to start only on right pages, yet having equal margins in all pages; without using the `geometry` package?*

Or, alternatively:

*Is there any way of using `geometry` such that I get what I desire without the layout of some pages changing as they currently do?*

Thank you all in advance for your time. Any help or insight will be greatly appreciated.

PS1: I have found several related questions; but I do not think it is a duplicate.

PS2: Also, I am aware I can do this manually; but that means that I have to revise the setting every time I change the content of the document; which is not handy nor very LaTeX-style.

Comment: Are the `mdframe`d elements breakable or floating? Otherwise, you can expect this spacing  issues any time you change very small dimensions --- have just one line more in a paragraph and then all things have to be re-collocated and underfull `vbox`es will happen.

Comment: Out of the four definitions that I have, two are breakable and two are not. In particular, definitions are not breakable. As far as I know, they are not floating. By the way, how can I make them floating? O: However, I'd expect LaTex to leave a lot of blank space at the end in a worst case scenario (which is what used to do without `geometry`), instead of re-spacing, which is what it does with `geometry` loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to change the twoside switch later so that it doesn't affect the layout:

```
\documentclass[openright]{report}
\makeatletter\@twosidetrue\makeatother
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{a}
\lipsum
\chapter{b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works and generates the desired output. Hence, I happily accept it! Thank you.